# Sending a java object in service

Tags: java, rest

I have simple POJO say User Object;

```
public class User{
 private String userid;
 private String emailid;
 private String name;
 ....setters and getters...
}
```

Now,I want to set some values using setter methods of User class.

So,if i want to send this object to through service.

```
    URL url = new URL("http://<servername>/example/someservice");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

what would be the best approach for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your data (class instance) to bytes (it's called **serialization**), send the bytes, and convert from bytes to data (it's called **deserialization**).

Please try having a look at [google](http://www.google.com/?q=Java%20serialization)

Some popular serialization options: in-built java serialization - binary, XML (text), JSON (text).